# Create protected routes in the client when using hashed routing

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I want to create protected routes in my client. I briefly wondered if user authentication could be done without a server, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005450/authenticate-without-using-a-server) answered that for me (i.e. it's a bad idea).

I'm already checking for the existence of a token at the root of my application (in the server).  The token is issued after a user is successfully authenticated.  So a user that is not logged in cannot access any private routes.

In my client, routing is done with hashed routes, like `<a href="#private">Private Page</a>`.  This approach does not make any calls to the server, which is the point since I don't want to make a round trip to the server if it's not necessary.  More importantly, this route does not require any data from the database, so no server call is made.  But, if an authenticated user alters the token, and then navigates to another protected route, they're still able to view that route, when I actually want to invalidate their session and log them out.

For routes that require authenticated data, this is my auth setup:

```
axios.get("/api/private-route", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: Cookies.get('token')
  }
})
```

And it's authenticated on the Express server with

```
router.get('/api/private-route', authenticateToken, (req, res, next) => { res.send(privateData) })
```

In order to protect a route in the client, I realize a round trip to the server is a must, so is making a simple `GET` request (like above) the only way to achieve authentication for routes that do not require backend data? I am not using any libraries/frameworks in the client.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is if a client-side protected route can show content that requires authentication when the client has not yet been authenticated, then you already have a problem.  That means an unauthenticated client has data it should not have.  Your server should not be providing the private data to the client at all if the client is not authenticated.  You need to go back a few steps and fix things at the source because right now you don't have proper security on data.  An unauthenticated client should never be handed data in the first place that it's not allowed to show.

Comment: This is not a matter of just having the client check with the server to see if the client is authenticated.  It's a matter of not even providing the data to the client unless it is authenticated.  So, the client never contains any data it's not allowed to show.

Comment: I should have clarified that I am checking for the existence of a token at the root of my application (in the server).  The token is issued after a user is successfully authenticated.  So, a user that's not logged in can't access any private routes. What I'm wondering is how to invalidate a user session if they alter the client-side token after they've been authenticated?  It seems to me the only way to accomplish this is to make an authentication request to the server on every protected route, regardless of whether or not the route requires server-side data.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to protect against if they alter the client-side token?  If they've already proven previously that they were once authenticated and allowed to see the data in the client what are you trying to protect against if they mess with the client token that was previously used to get that data?  I'm trying to understand what the real problem is here you're trying to protect?  So, far this is mostly an XY problem where you're deep in the weeds of your implementation without telling us what the high level security issue is.

Comment: If you want to re-verify that their client token is still good, then you will have to access the server to verify that.  But, if you're only using that to decide whether to show some data that is already in the client, then that's not really doing much from a security perspective.  The data is already in the client and can be accessed whether than server-side check passes or not.  In fact, a hacker could just short circuit the server-side check anyway to always say it was OK.

Comment: At a high level, I'm creating a single page application in vanilla JS (rather than using a library like React), and then tying it to an Express backend.  To make it usable, I need things like user authentication. I haven't done this before at a production level, so I'm trying to apply software development concepts (like security) to this project.  Your second answer addresses my question, which is that a trip to the server is, in fact, necessary to authenticate a token. I believe that's how authentication in a library like React also works.